# Vue not updating input that depends on another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building something like this, where the country I pick will dictate the phone country code automatically.

[image]

Both the country and countryCode are stored in a customer object, and when I'm changing the country's value, the trigger is correctly called and I can see the country code changing in Vue dev tools, however the related input does not update. This is my code:

```
    data: function () {
        return {
            customer: {},
            countries: this.$store.state.settings.countries,
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        var defaultCountry = _.find(this.countries, { default: true });

        this.customer.country = defaultCountry.name;
        this.customer.countryCode = defaultCountry.code;
    },
    methods: {
        updateCountryCode: function(country) {
            this.customer.countryCode = country.code;
        },
    }
```

And this is the relevant HTML:

```
<vSelect 
label="name" 
v-model="customer.country" 
:options="countries" 
:onChange="updateCountryCode">
</vSelect>

<input type="text" disabled :value="customer.countryCode">
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I see the data being updated on dev tools but it doesn't act as reactive and my country code input stays the same?

Comment: You should define your customer object like so
`customer: {country: null, countryCode: null,},`

Comment: What? That worked! I was assuming that since I was setting a default value upon created() I wouldn't need to assign those values in the empty object. Any idea why this is needed? Also, please add this as a separate answer so I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your customer object like so customer:

```
{
    country: null, // or some other default value
    countryCode: null,
},
```

You can find more details in the documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you shoul do it or  @Nora's method of initializing the object properties to `null`

```
 updateCountryCode: function(country) {
   this.$set(this.customer, 'countryCode', country.code) 
},
```

And the reason is because of [change detection caveats in vue reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Comment: Thanks for this - I wasn't sure if this was within the infamous Vue caveats or not but now I see it definitely is.

Comment: @Anonymous happy to help :)